# calling userdefined method using spring AOP before a method is called

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am using Spring AOP and below is the service class and aspect.
I want to call assignValues() method before when multiply() is being called.

```
package com.test.service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class MathService {  
    int a,b;
    public void assignValues() {
        a=3;
        b=10;
    }

    public Integer multiply(){
        System.out.println("--multiply called---");
        int res = a*b;
        System.out.println("values :: " + a+ "*" + b +"= " + res);
        return res;
    }
     public Integer multiply(int a, int b){
        int res = a*b;
        System.out.println(a+ "*" + b +"= " + res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Aspect class below:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TimeLoggingAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.test.service.*.*(..))")
    public void userAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("@Around: Before calculation-"+ new Date());
        joinPoint.proceed();
        System.out.println("@Around: After calculation-"+ new Date());
    } 


     @Before("execution(* com.test.service.assignValues(..))")          
        public void logBeforeV1(JoinPoint joinPoint)
        {
            System.out.println("-before- : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        } 
}
```

Test class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
public class SpringAOPTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //...
       MathService mathService = ctx.getBean(MathService.class);
      mathService.multiply();//i want to call assignValues() method to assign the values of a and b through AOP, before method multiply() is called 
   }
}
```

How to call assignValues() method using aspect ***@Before*** whenever multiply() is being called.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is `@PostConstruct`, and what you really *really* want is to use constructor injection and move this initialization to the constructor.

Comment: @chrylis - Its not constructor injection i want..here i just made a sample(may be i could have given better) with simple example of what i want...When ever multiply() method is being called i want to call the assignValues() method before multiply() is being invoked..and i cannot touch the MathService class or modify anything in that class..Inputs would be helpful.thanks.

Comment: How about fixing your pointcut? You forgot the class name `MathService`. So the pointcut should be `execution(* com.test.service.MathService.assignValues(..))`. If this helps trigger your aspect advice, please let me know, then I will convert the comment into an answer you can accept. I will also help you call the other method from the advice if that's what you want.